# MSBuild Not Resolving Parameters inside Path

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, t4

i have to run text transform file using ms build so i am using Transform as target. In order to run it in my project i have to pass some path to fetch resource dlls. so my command is

```
D:\WorkSpace\Projects\Client\Dev\Project\Lw.Domain.Project>msbuild  /tv:15.0 /t:transform /p:TransformFile="ProjectEntityModelGenerator.tt" /p:SolutionDir=".." /p:FrameworkVersion=4 /p:MetaModelFolder="$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)" /p:BaseResourceFolder="$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)" /p:FrameworkReference="package" /p:IsFromMSBuild="true"
```

But it is not resolving the path, so i am getting issue like below,

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(340,5):
>   error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'D:\WorkSpace\Projects\Client\Dev\Project\Lw.Domain.Project\$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)Lw.System.Metamodel.dll'.

```
 [D:\WorkSpace\Projects\Client\Dev\Project\Lw.Domain.Project\Lw.Domain.Project.csproj]
```

Am I missing something in my csproj file? Below is my csproj file configuration,

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Get the Visual Studio version – defaults to 10: -->
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Keep the next element all on one line: -->
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <SolutionDir>$(SolutionDir)</SolutionDir>
    <FrameworkVersion>$(FrameworkVersion)</FrameworkVersion>
    <MetaModelFolder>$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)\</MetaModelFolder>
    <BaseResourceFolder>$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)\</BaseResourceFolder>
    <IsFromMSBuild>$(IsFromMSBuild)</IsFromMSBuild>
    <ComputedSolutionDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(ProjectDir),"..\\"))))</ComputedSolutionDir>
    <DomainResourceFolder>$(SolutionDir)..\Product\Lw.Domain\bin\$(Configuration)\</DomainResourceFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '15.0'" />
```

Comment: *Am I missing something in my csproj file?* I don't know; you didn't post your CSProj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested on my local project, and found that Properties cannot be passed in command line using the same syntax `"$()"` in csproj file.

You need pass to the command line the exact physical path for the BaseResourceFolder. And from below error. You missed a "\" at the end of the value for BaseResourceFolder too.

> 'D:\WorkSpace\Projects\Client\Dev\Project\Lw.Domain.Project\$(SolutionDir)\packages\LW.Framework$(FrameworkVersion)Lw.System.Metamodel.dll'.

```
/p:BaseResourceFolder="(phsical path to BaseResourceFolder)\"
```

Hope you find above helpful.

Comment: Hi @azhahes.s Did you check out above answer, How was it going? Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Thanks @levi. Please check out my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817808/beforebuild-target-of-all-the-projects-are-executing-at-first-on-solution-build)